# Scroll view hides the first child in the layout

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I have certain widgets in `LinearLayout` which is a child of `ScrollView`. The problem is that the first widget in this case, the widget named "Title 1" is not visible it goes beyond the screen size as seen in this image,

[image]

I have tried the following but still it does not show my Title 1.

1. Added an attribute `android:fillViewport="true"` in `ScrollView` but it did not work.
2. Added a `layout_gravity`(`center_horizontal | center_vertical`) attribute but it didn't work.
3. This question was specific to the OP's design [Android ScrollView fillViewport not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780619/android-scrollview-fillviewport-not-working) and did not help much.

**Note:** I want the widget visible by not using any margin/padding attributes.

The code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    >

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"           
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
           >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"                     
                        android:text="Title 1"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 2"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 3"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 4"
                        />
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 5"
                        /> 

                        <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 6"
                    /> 

                    <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 7"
                    />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 8"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 9"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 10"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 11"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 12"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:background="@color/green"
                        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                        android:text="Title 13"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            style="@style/tabLayoutStyle"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**EDIT 1**

Changed height of LinearLayout(Inside scrollview) from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` but still didn't work.

Comment: This problem occur only in preview screen ?

Comment: Change height of _LInearLayout(Inside scrollview)_  from `match_parent` to `wrap_content`

Comment: @user7832102 Tried on physical device and emulator.

Comment: @Piyush Did that still no luck !

Comment: what is your project theme style ?

Comment: @user7832102 `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar`

Comment: are u using fragment or activity?

Comment: Can you change the theme with Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar

Comment: @Manish Activity

Comment: First, try removing ConstraintLayout enclosing ScrollView, if this doesn't make any sense then just tell me what are these child view? are they independent view or is it a list?

Comment: @rajatsingh They are independent widgets didn't see the code ? I want them in a scroll view only else how will scrolling happen ?

Comment: I got your error. just Add android:layout_marginTop="10dp" insted of android:paddingTop="10dp".

Comment: First, make the `height` of parent LinearLayout `match_parent` after that remove 'ConstraintLayout' and after that make scrollView height `match_parent`

Comment: @rajatsingh  I need constraint layout man so that I can show the content above the toolbar

Comment: Can't you use coordinator layout for that?

Comment: @rajatsingh Nope if I use that then my `ScrollView` will go behind the `TabLayout` making the bottom of the widgets in the `ScrollView` invisible.

Comment: edited my comment **I use that then my ScrollView will go behind the TabLayout making the bottom of the widgets in the ScrollView invisible.** to rectify this see for scroll behaviors here
https://android.jlelse.eu/scrolling-behavior-for-appbars-in-android-41aff9c5c468

Comment: @rajatsingh page not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to [Mohammad Asheri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611525/4706252), I added the following attribute and it worked flawlessly,

From [Mohammad Asheri's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611525/4706252) I added this attribute,`app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"` which aligns the `ScrollView` to the top and prevents the child `View`'s from going above the device height but then another problem occurred, the `View`'s at the bottom were hidden by the `tabLayout` So I added this attribute to correct this, changed the `layout_height` to `wrap_content` and added this, `app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true"` this attribute does not exceed the resulting dimension which is `tabLayout` in this case. This is from the constraint layout version 1.1 onwards refer this [ConstraintLayout 1.1.0 different from 1.0.2, is it a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49912075/constraintlayout-1-1-0-different-from-1-0-2-is-it-a-bug)

Also the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout) describe it perfectly

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:layout_constrainedHeight=”true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

Answer (score 2):

The result is add to post.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/view_pager"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:text="Title 1"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 2"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 3"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 4"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 5"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 6"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 7"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 8"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 9"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 10"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 11"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 12"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:background="@color/green"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:text="Title 13"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remove the TabLayout, then the first TextView will appear. The problem is that you use the TabLayout wrong

Comment: This should be a comment and not an answer.`Remove the TabLayout, then the first TextView will appear` no this will not work since the tablayout is at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Your `TabLayout` maybe the reason the first value is not visible. The first item on your list is probably under the `TabLayout` and not visible.

There is no need for the `ConstrainLayout`. Make orientation of your `LinearLayout` vertical. You can use this sample

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
    style="@style/tabLayoutStyle"
    />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/view_pager"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:text="Title 1"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 2"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 3"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 4"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 5"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 6"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 7"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 8"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 9"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 10"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 11"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 12"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="Title 13"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: `The first item on your list is probably under the TabLayout and not visible.` totally wrong how come did you even look at my code ?

Comment: `There is no need for the ConstrainLayout. Make orientation of your LinearLayout vertical. You can use this sample` How come man I need the tab layout at the bottom you have placed it top as per your wish. The tab needs to be at bottom and the widgets should be hidden by the tab layout at the bottom.

Comment: @GeekDroid if you want the TabLayout at the bottom, place it after the ScrollView

Comment: That would hide the TextView's 11,12,13(If you could understand)

Comment: @GeekDroid just try it, it is not suppose to. And it is not standard practice to place TabLayout at the bottom of the screen